# Status of tuxonice in 12.04?

Tags: kernel, 12.04

Ubuntu 12.04 contains tuxonice-userui package (userspace utilities for TuxOnIce), but fails to provide tuxonice-patched kernels - making the former package useless.

What is the status of TuxOnIce in Ubuntu 12.04? Is it to be part of this distribution, or not? If yes, why kernels are missing, if not, what is tuxonice-userui doing here?

Answer (score 3):

TuxOnIce kernel packages and an updated tuxonice-userui package are available from:

https://launchpad.net/~tuxonice/+archive/ppa

Getting TuxOnIce is as easy as adding the PPA and installing the following packages:

"tuxonice-userui linux-generic-tuxonice linux-headers-generic-tuxonice"

Note that on Ubuntu 12.04 hibernate is disabled by default. Re-enable it as follows:
https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/ubuntu-help/power-hibernate.html

Answer (score 1):

The kernel team is not intending on providing any patches kernels for TuxOnIce so I suspect that the userspace is of little use.  TuxOnIce has never made any real upstream progress.  After the last attempt at upstreaming there was agreement to pool all the best bits of the completing implementations into one upstream approach and we expect that to come over time, though progress is glacial.  Ubuntu deliberately selects and uses the upstream solutions as they have the greatest support.

The userspace componets would remain so that people who wish to roll their own kernels can at least get the utilities without having to build those themselves.